Prove that the (coordinate ring of) quantum plane is Noetherian.
The quantum plane is defined as
$$
k_q\{x,y\}:=k\{x,y\}/(xy-qyx),
$$
that is, the free (noncommutative, unital & associative) $k-$algebra where we set $xy=qyx$, where $0\neq q \in k$, $k$ is a field (I think we usually ask that $k$ to be algebraically closed).
I want to show that $k_q\{x,y\}$ is Noetherian (I mean both left and right Noetherian).
I believe that I have proved $\mathbf{B}:=\{y^ix^j|i,j \geq 0\}$ is a basis of $k_q\{x,y\}$ (when we view $k_q\{x,y\}$ as a $k-$vector space).
I want to use the idea of Hilbert basis theorem to prove the result:
Take any $(0) \neq I\unlhd_l k_q\{x,y\}$. By $\mathbf{B}$ being a basis, we know that every element in $I$ can be expressed as $\sum_{i}y^ip_i(x)$, where $p_i(x) \in k[x]$. But I am kind of stuck here.

Spelling is Noetherian

@J.W.Tanner Thanks, fixed.

For a proof of the noncommutative Hilbert basis theorem (and an immediate application to your example), see Theorem 1.14 (p17) in Noncommutative Noetherian Rings 2nd ed. (2004) by Goodearl and Warfield. The statement is as follows: Let $\alpha$ be an automorphism of a ring $R$ and $S = R[x;\alpha]$. If $R$ is right (left) noetherian, then so is $S$. The automorphism is $x \mapsto q^{-1} x$ (p14).
